# How to close automatically div tag when i open new div tag

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a GridView Control which dynamically generate multiple `a link` and `div  tags` in gridview control.
**My Requirement is :**
if Gridview display more than 50 records its generate 50 `a link`  and `div` tags when i click on first row show anchor link its show first row div tags `FirstName and LastName` Records details again if i click on any row `a anchor` link first opened `div tags` close automatically and opened new div tags which row i clicked.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridParent" runat="server">
     <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField>
         <ItemTemplate>
          <table>
            <tr>
             <td>  
               Username : <%# Eval("Username") %>
               <a href="#" onclick="ShowDiv(this);">Show</a>
               <div id="div1" style='display:none;'>
                First Name: <%# Eval("FirstName") %>
                Last Name: <%# Eval("LastName") %>
               </div>
             </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
         </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  $('.more-info').css('display', 'none');
  $(this).next().css('display', 'block');
});
```

```css
.more-info {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Username : "Username"
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Show</a>
      <div id="div1" class="more-info">
        First Name: "FirstName" Last Name: "LastName"
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Username : "Username"
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Show</a>
      <div id="div2" class="more-info">
        First Name: "FirstName" Last Name: "LastName"
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Username : "Username"
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Show</a>
      <div id="div3" class="more-info">
        First Name: "FirstName" Last Name: "LastName"
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```